# Adding Dictionaries with lists to a Pandas DataFrame (pd.DataFrame(dict) vs df.append(dict))

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am having a problem with adding a dictionary which contains lists into a pandas data-frame. My data looks like this:

```
a = {'id':[0,1,2,3,4,5,6],
 'value':[354,324,211,78,644,198,342]}
```

When you add a dictionary to a pandas dataframe, it adds the elements of each list to a row in the dataframe, like this:

```
test1 = pd.DataFrame(a)
```

But then, when I try to append a dictionary (the same dictionary in this case), each column then contains a list.

```
test1 = test1.append(a, ignore_index = True)
```

I have tried to find out why this is the case. Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `pd.DataFrame` again:

```
test1.append(pd.DataFrame(a), ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
    id  value
0    0    354
1    1    324
2    2    211
3    3     78
4    4    644
5    5    198
6    6    342
7    0    354
8    1    324
9    2    211
10   3     78
11   4    644
12   5    198
13   6    342
```

Or use `pd.concat`

```
pd.concat([test1,pd.DataFrame(a)])
```